# Stock ticker horizontal scrolling view in IOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

I'd like to display a horizontal scrolling view like a "stock ticker" but actually containing different content. I've looked at a few solutions and unfortunately they all make the same assumption that the content is fixed and repeats, ie. cycles around endlessly.

In my case, I want to display an item once, scroll it across and then never show it again. My data arrives asynchronously so there could already be something moving when it arrives or there may be nothing on the screen at all. The items would appear at the right and move to the left as they arrive, in order.

My  thought is to put the content in a UIView then somehow animate the motion, adding another UIView to the right of it once there is space to show it. But I'm a bit out of my depth here as to how to implement this so some pointers would be very useful. Alternatively some sample code of something similar would be extremely useful!

Thanks.

Comment: I'm working on the same thing. Did you find a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this!
What I have done is that I am using 5 views. 2 on the left of the screen 2 on the right and 1 in the middle.Also, my scrollView content size if 5 times the screen (so to accomodate 5 views). Now, whevever the user scrolles, my code calls a method `layoutSubviews` which checks if the scroll has reached certain distance and then bring the content offset to center and also move the views so that user do not see any jerk. at the end i hav added animation which continuously scrolls the views.